# Add a date picker to an already existing html form with Django

Tags: python, django, datepicker

I have this template that i use for my Django app :

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'GenerateXL/form.css' %}">
    <title>
        app title
    </title>
</head>

<body style="margin-top: 30px; margin-left: 30px;">
    <h1 style="text-align:center"><span style="font-family:Georgia,serif"><span style="color:#006600">
    django app
    </span></span></h1>
    
    <div class="wrapper">
    
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    
    <div class="left">
    <h3> import file <h3>
    <br>
    <input type="file"
        title="Upload SPORT"
        name="sport"
        style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px;"
        required="required">
    <p>
        <input type="submit"
            value="Upload"
            name="sportt"
            style="border: 1px solid green; padding: 5px; border-radius: 2px; cursor: pointer;">
    </p>
    **<!-- I would like to add a datepicker -->**
    </div>
    
    <div class="right">
    
    <h3> Authenticate <h3>
    
    <div class="wrapper">
    
    <div class="left">
    <h5> Connect to proxy : <h5>
    <input type="text"
        title="Id_proxy"
        name="nnn"
        placeholder="nnn"
        style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px;"
        required="required">
    <input type="password"
        title="Password_proxy"
        name="MDP_proxy"
        placeholder="mot de passe proxy"
        style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px;"
        required="required">
    </div>
    
    <div class="right">
    <h5> Connect SP : <h5>
    <input type="text"
        title="Id_Sharepoint"
        name="Login_sp"
        placeholder="Login Sharepoint"
        style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px;"
        required="required">
    <input type="password"
        title="Password_sharepoint"
        name="MDP_sp"
        placeholder="mot de passe Sharepoint"
        style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px;"
        required="required">
    </div>
    
    </div>
    
    </div>
    
    </form>
    </div>
```

I want to add a date picker (actually two of them) in the specified location in the code, the dates would then be sent as a variable when user click on submit form.
I tried following the walkthrough tutorial for django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus but it just doesn't fit right for me, i'm not using any generic view.
If more details are needed please let me know.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're looking this up, here's how i did it (simplest way i could), I used XDSoft DateTimePicker, it is a jQuery plugin.

first include the required css and js files of the plugin to your html by adding the following code inside head tag

```
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" integrity="sha256-DOS9W6NR+NFe1fUhEE0PGKY/fubbUCnOfTje2JMDw3Y=" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js" integrity="sha256-FEqEelWI3WouFOo2VWP/uJfs1y8KJ++FLh2Lbqc8SJk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
```

then add the datepicker js code where you want to have your datepicker in your html body

```
<input id="start" type="text" name="debut">
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#start").datetimepicker({
            format : 'd/m/Y',
            });
        });
    </script>
```

and it's gonna look like this :
[image]

Note : it is interpreted as string, so i personally had to convert it to datetime as i'm working with python.